# Unlock dll after using Assembly.LoadFrom() method

Tags: c#, plugins

I am creating **Visual Studio Plugin.**

I am loading DLL using **Assembly.LoadFrom** method as I want to load referenced DLL also.
I need to be able to update these DLL while the system is running but it appears that after calling Assembly.LoadFrom the DLL is subsequently locked.

I can not use below code as this will not load referenced dll

```
byte[] readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("MyPlugin.dll");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(readAllBytes);
```

How to load DLL without locking DLL or How to unlock DLL after loading DLL?

Comment: please check on this link, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803698/update-applications-libraries-dlls-during-runtime